# Cocoa Mac app and NSTableView don't refresh with NSArrayController and NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: refresh, nstableview, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsarraycontroller, ticoredatasync

I'm developing a new Core Data app and I created an NSArrayController (Entity Mode) to make bindings, it works very well but when the SQLite store changes (changes come from other clients using TICoreDataSync library) I force a tableView reload with no success. Here the code:

```
NSError *saveError = nil;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&saveError];
    if (saveError != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, saveError);
    }
[arrayController fetch:nil];
[tableView reloadData];
```

If I close the app and start it again I can see changes in my tableView but I would like it to refresh automatically. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` to update your context when TICDS makes changes?

You should implement this delegate method:

```
-(void)documentSyncManager:(TICDSDocumentSyncManager *)aSyncManager 
    didMakeChangesToObjectsInBackgroundContextAndSaveWithNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

Make sure you invoke `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` on the appropriate thread.

Also worth looking at a sync framework I am developing called [Ensembles](http://ensembles.io). TICDS is not being maintained very much these days — I've worked on it in the past — and Ensembles is quite a bit easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me the Ensembles framework, I'll have a look, I'm working on the OSX client of an already working iOS app using TICDS so I should plan a migration. I tried the delegate method with no success:

-(void)documentSyncManager:(TICDSDocumentSyncManager *)aSyncManager
didMakeChangesToObjectsInBackgroundContextAndSaveWithNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    [arrayController fetch:nil];
    [tableView reloadData];
}

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line before fetch and it works:

```
[arrayController setManagedObjectContext:[[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext]];
```

Good for me that it works but I don't understand why I need to set it everytime I start fetching, the managedObjectContext is set at startup or it wouldn't show values once the app started.